# Insert some spaces into a string oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle table called `MYTABLE` , with a `prog_model` column. 
I am trying the `CASE` (if oracle) to insert some spaces into my `prog_model` depending of the string length.

My issue is that I'm getting `ORA-00936 error missing expression ligne 3 c18` I have no idea where it comes from being a super noob in SQL, any ideas?

Here is my .sql :

```
SELECT prog_model,
  CASE Length(prog_model)
    WHEN 11 THEN Insert('   ',2,3,prog_model)
    WHEN 12 THEN Insert('  ',2,3,prog_model)
    WHEN 13 THEN Insert(' ',2,3,prog_model)
  END
FROM MYTABLE;
```

EDIT:

Basically in `prog_model` I **always** have a string from 11 to 14 characters :

if 11 chars , "ABCEFGHIJKL" --> "ABC_ _ _EFGHIKL"

if 12 chars , "ABCEFGHIJKLM" --> "ABC_ _EFGHIJKLM"

Comment: Use \s instead of blank space

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use the [MySQL `insert()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) in Oracle. Oracle doesn't have this. From looking at the MySQL docs, it seems `prog_model` should be the first argument - however I don't know exactly what you need it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of an `insert()` *function* in Oracle.  There is one in MySQL, though.  Your error is probably because `insert` is a keyword.

If you wanted the spaces at the beginning, you would use the [`lpad()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm#OLADM593) only:

```
select lpad(prog_model, 14, ' ')
```

You seem to want them in the middle.  I think this goes like:

```
select substr(prog_model, 1, 3) || lpad(substr(prog_model, 4), 11, ' ')
```

I might have the length wrong in the second part.  Without sample data, it is challenging to figure out the exact length.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try it out , I did some edits and here the insert function I'm using : [oracle_functions](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bidv1221/desktop/BIDVD/GUID-BBA975C7-B2C5-4C94-A007-28775680F6A5.htm#BILUG685)

Comment: That's a link to Oracle Data Visualization Desktop. if you are using that and not a standard SQL tool then you should probably tag it.

Comment: I am using a standard SQL tool, so yeah it explains why Insert is not working there. @WilliamRobertson

Comment: Standard Oracle SQL functions are here (12.1): https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

How about this (three approaches to try, including Gordon's `substr`/`lpad`):

```
with demo (prog_model) as
     ( select 'ABCEFGHIJKL' from dual union all
       select 'ABCEFGHIJKLM' from dual union all
       select 'ABCEFGHIJKLMN' from dual union all
       select 'ABCEFGHIJKLMNO' from dual )
select prog_model
     , regexp_replace(prog_model,'(...)(.*$)', '\1'|| rpad(' ',14 - length(prog_model)) ||'\2') as result1
     , case length(prog_model)
           when 11 then regexp_replace(prog_model,'(...)(.*$)', '\1   \2')
           when 12 then regexp_replace(prog_model,'(...)(.*$)', '\1  \2')
           when 13 then regexp_replace(prog_model,'(...)(.*$)', '\1 \2')
           when 14 then prog_model
       end as result2
     , substr(prog_model,1,3) || lpad(substr(prog_model,4),11) as result3
from demo;

PROG_MODEL     RESULT1        RESULT2        RESULT3
-------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
ABCEFGHIJKL    ABC   EFGHIJKL ABC   EFGHIJKL ABC   EFGHIJKL
ABCEFGHIJKLM   ABC  EFGHIJKLM ABC  EFGHIJKLM ABC  EFGHIJKLM
ABCEFGHIJKLMN  ABC EFGHIJKLMN ABC EFGHIJKLMN ABC EFGHIJKLMN
ABCEFGHIJKLMNO ABCEFGHIJKLMNO ABCEFGHIJKLMNO ABCEFGHIJKLMNO
```

Comment: looks super difficult compared to what I need to do, no?

Comment: OK, Gordon's `substr`/`lpad` is a simpler way to do it, with a bit of tweaking to match your test data. Adding...